# Using "adjust" option for lonely PSUs in R survey package: why don't single-PSU strata variances change when data in other strata change?

Tags: r, survey, variance

I have survey data from a stratified simple random sampling design where some strata contain only a single sampling unit (even though the strata population size may be >1).  These are referred to as "lonely PSUs" in the R survey package (http://r-survey.r-forge.r-project.org/survey/exmample-lonely.html).  There are several options for dealing with this situation and the one I'm interested in is the "adjust" option.

The documentation for `options(survey.lonely.psu="adjust")` states that

> "the data for the single-PSU stratum are centered at the sample grand
>   mean rather than the stratum mean."

In experimenting with this option I had expected that the variance for my single-PSU stratum would change if I changed the data in another stratum but that wasn't the case.  Here is a small example:

```
library(survey)
options(survey.lonely.psu="adjust")

# sample 1
dat1 <- data.frame(N = c(3, 3, 2), h = c(1, 1, 2), y = c(2, 6, 15))
survey1 <- svydesign(~1, fpc = ~N, strata = ~h, data = dat1)
svyby(~y, by = ~h, design = survey1, FUN = svytotal)
```

In the results note the standard error for strata 2, which is the single-PSU stratum:

```
  h  y        se
1 1 12  3.464102
2 2 30 21.213203
```

Now if I change the data in strata 1 like so

```
# sample 2
(dat2 <- data.frame(N = c(3, 3, 2), h = c(1, 1, 2), y = c(200, 600, 15)))
(survey2 <- svydesign(~1, fpc = ~N, strata = ~h, data = dat2))
svyby(~y, by = ~h, design = survey2, FUN = svytotal)
```

The results change as expected for stratum 1, but the standard error is still the same for stratum 2

```
  h    y       se
1 1 1200 346.4102
2 2   30  21.2132
```

Am I mis-interpreting what the documentation means or might this be a bug?

FYI, here is my sessionInfo:

```
R version 3.1.3 (2015-03-09)
Platform: i386-w64-mingw32/i386 (32-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1
other attached packages:
[1] survey_3.30-3
```

**EDIT**

My interpretation of the initial answers I received was that the variance adjustment doesn't take effect when the data are subset using the `svyby` function.  However, when I compare the variances of the totals for the stratified population with the variance for the total population it appears that, just as when there are no lonely PSUs, the variance of the total is simply the variance of the independently sampled stratum variances:

```
> vcov(svyby(~y, by = ~h, design = survey1, FUN = svytotal))
   1   2
1 12   0
2  0 450

> vcov(svytotal(~y, survey1))
    y
y 462
```

It seems that the latter variance should be different if there is some sort of centering to the grand mean going on when all the data are combined.

As a related question, here is a comparison of `svyby` when estimating means versus totals:

```
> svyby(~y, by = ~h, design = survey1, FUN = svymean)
  h  y    se
1 1  4 1.155
2 2 15 0.000

> svyby(~y, by = ~h, design = survey1, FUN = svytotal)
  h  y     se
1 1 12  3.464
2 2 30 21.213
```

I'm confused here as to why there is a variance estimated for stratum 2 (which contains a lonley PSU) when estimating a total but not when estimating a mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Short Answer

**TL;DR**: The survey package currently has a bug with the 'adjust' option when using `svytotal()` but works fine for `svymean()`. This blog post gets into the details:
https://www.practicalsignificance.com/posts/bugs-with-singleton-strata/

### Long Answer

Currently, with the 'adjust' option, the survey package is just centering the lonely PSU around 0 and then adding the squares to the estimated covariance matrix. This is totally reasonable for `svymean()`, `svyratio()`, and many other functions, but it is a mistake for `svytotal()`.

Why?

##### Background on how the survey package estimates variances using influence functions

The R package estimates variances using the method of linearization based on influence functions. This blog post explains what that means and gives a few references:

https://www.practicalsignificance.com/posts/survey-covariances-using-influence-functions/#how-does-this-work

Essentially, for a statistic of interest, we calculate its variance by expressing it as a weighted total of influence functions and estimating the variance of that weighted total. For statistics such as means or ratios, the weighted total of the influence functions is always 0. Totals are a special case, where the influence functions are equal to the original variable, and so their sum is generally nonzero.

##### What `survey.lonely.psu = 'adjust'` is supposed to do

The documentation for the "adjust" option says that it works by "recentering" the lonely PSU. If the PSU wasn't lonely, we could get a reasonable estimate of its variance contribution by calculating the squared difference between the PSU's total and the average PSU total in its stratum. But because it's the only PSU in its stratum, that difference is zero. Theoretically, with `survey.lonely.psu = 'adjust'`, we instead estimate its variance contribution by calculating the squared difference between the PSU's total and average PSU total **across all strata**.

##### What the survey package actually does and why that's a problem for `svytotal()`

Because the survey package uses the method of linearization based on influence functions, the average PSU total **across all strata** is zero for every statistic **other than totals**. I think because of this fact, the survey package was written so that when the user specifies `survey.lonely.psu = 'adjust'`, the variance contribution of the lonely PSU is taken by just squaring the PSU total (i.e. subtracting zero). That is clever and works for means, ratios, etc. But it fails for totals because of the unique property that the total of their influence functions is nonzero.

https://www.practicalsignificance.com/posts/bugs-with-singleton-strata/

Answer (score 2):

Analysis of a subset of a complex design is basically equivalent to analysis setting the sampling weights for observations outside the subset to zero.  That means these observations don't enter into the 'grand mean'.

Comment: Thanks Thomas.  Maybe using `svyby` isn't the best way to try and understand what the `adjust` option is doing.  Nonetheless, I edited my question to show how the sum of the strata variances (where stratum #2 has a lonely PSU) is equivalent to the population variance.  It seems like they shouldn't be equivalent if there was centering to the grand mean going on.  Additionally, I'm perplexed why there isn't a variance for the stratum #2 mean when using `svyby` but there is for the total.

Comment: I think there actually is a bug with the `"adjust"` option specifically for `svytotal()`, but not for `svymean()`. I tried to explain it here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/73588156/5373794

Answer (score 1):

I believe that those settings only really begin to take effect at the point that the singleton rows are combined somehow with other records?  So a `svyby()` that isolates the singleton record doesn't capture the variance of other records, but a `svymean()` that includes the singleton record alongside others will behave differently depending on the setting.  Notice the SE of each `svymean` call differs:

```
options(digits=22)
library(survey)
options(survey.lonely.psu="adjust")


# sample 1
dat1 <- data.frame(h = c(1, 1, 2 ), w=1:3 , y = c(2, 6, 15))
survey1 <- svydesign(~1,strata=~h, w=~w,data = dat1)
svyby(~y, ~h,survey1,svymean)
svymean(~y, survey1)

# sample 2
dat1 <- data.frame(h = c(1, 1, 2 ), w=1:3 , y = c(200, 600, 15))
survey1 <- svydesign(~1,strata=~h, w=~w,data = dat1)
svyby(~y, ~h,survey1,svymean)
svymean(~y, survey1)


options(survey.lonely.psu="average")

# sample 1
dat1 <- data.frame(h = c(1, 1, 2 ), w=1:3 , y = c(2, 6, 15))
survey1 <- svydesign(~1,strata=~h, w=~w,data = dat1)
svyby(~y, ~h,survey1,svymean)
svymean(~y, survey1)

# sample 2
dat1 <- data.frame(h = c(1, 1, 2 ), w=1:3 , y = c(200, 600, 15))
survey1 <- svydesign(~1,strata=~h, w=~w,data = dat1)
svyby(~y, ~h,survey1,svymean)
svymean(~y, survey1)


options(survey.lonely.psu="remove")

# sample 1
dat1 <- data.frame(h = c(1, 1, 2 ), w=1:3 , y = c(2, 6, 15))
survey1 <- svydesign(~1,strata=~h, w=~w,data = dat1)
svyby(~y, ~h,survey1,svymean)
svymean(~y, survey1)

# sample 2
dat1 <- data.frame(h = c(1, 1, 2 ), w=1:3 , y = c(200, 600, 15))
survey1 <- svydesign(~1,strata=~h, w=~w,data = dat1)
svyby(~y, ~h,survey1,svymean)
svymean(~y, survey1)
```

Comment: Thanks Anthony.  Your examples were a little different from mine since your weights were mis-specified (should be `w=c(3/2, 3/2, 2/1)`, your survey design was with-replacement since `fpc` was not included, and you looked at means instead of totals.  Nonetheless you raised a good point and it led me to compare `svymeans` and `svytotals`, with and without `svyby`.  I'm still a little perplexed though at what is going on so I'll try to edit my original question to further illustrate.

Comment: @Bryan get rid of the weights and the different `lonely.psu` option results still all differ.  dr. lumley's answer is correct

Answer (score 1):

Backing out your result using the TSL variance formula, we have stratum 2 variance = 21.213203^2 = 450.  Divide by sampling fraction you get s^2 = 900. 900 is 30^2. Unless I'm missing something it looks like the package is assuming the subgroup population mean is 0.  This is true for linearized means but not for totals.

Comment: This is correct. The survey package has had a bug with the 'adjust' option for some time now. You are right that it is just centering the lonely PSU around 0 and then adding the squares to the estimated covariance matrix. That's a bug. What it should be doing is centering the lonely PSU around the mean from the average PSU across all strata. Here's a reproducible example demonstrating the bug:
https://github.com/bschneidr/r-forge-survey-mirror/issues/5

Comment: Ended up writing a blog post on precisely this bug. The survey package's behavior makes sense for `svymean()` but is definitely a bug for `svytotal()`. The population mean and weighted sample mean of the influence functions is zero for means, ratios, etc., but totals are an exception. 

https://www.practicalsignificance.com/posts/bugs-with-singleton-strata/